# Best way to use Security when invoking web-services on your server

Tags: android, web-services, security

Every single  screen in my application is composed from data that comes from my server.
This server exposes many different types of web-services, based on WSDLs, that simply return one string containing a JSON.

Now, I am reaching the stage where I want to put this server online and I am concerned with the security aspects around it.

What is the best approach? Although the data going across mobile app and server is not exactly sensitive, I don't want it all open across the web.

Would just establishing a SSL channel be enough? I am also concerned with how the security will impact the performance of the application, in terms of sending and receiving data.

Is there any best practice document that maybe I should follow?

Thanks everyone,
Felipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question doesn't specify what specific kind of 'security' you are looking for !

- If you are worried about unauthorized accesses, you need to implement user accounts where user will have credentials to log in.
- You should consider [API keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface_key) if you want authorized and authenticated API access.
- If you want data confidentiality on the wire. Sure, SSL is the way to go. And to answer your question, [SSL/TLS is not computationally expensive any more](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html).
- From system security perspective of your server, make sure that the OS, Web Server and other softwares are patched. Open no more ports than necessary. If you have a ssh port open, preferably have key based authentication (or a very strong password if key based auth isn't possible)

Answer (score 2):

For "Data in Motion" (ie: transferring between device and server) your absolute best bet is SSL.

There are only a few primary ways to attack SSL.

The first is if they have a man in the middle server setup that can issue their own certificates for your domain.  This would make the client think that their server is the real one, meanwhile their server would grab the packets, decrypt them, store the data then reencrypt it using the real SSL certificate and send it on to your server.  A few SSL cert companies have been busted lately for supplying certs that did this.  However, the expense in setting this up means that they really just want high value targets.

The second is if they have something installed on either your server or the device itself that can insert itself somewhere between the app and the network api.  The idea here being to be able to capture the data either after decryption or before encryption.  Android and other devices have been shown to already have this type of software installed, but supposedly it's *only* used for debugging network related issues.

Point is, get an SSL certificate, install it and worry about other things.